# How to walk through a graph?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have the following tree

```
     1
    2 3
   4 5 6
  7 8 9 0
```

Now i want to walk through all possible paths trough the tree. It is always possible to move to adjacent numbers from the row below. For example

`1 2 4 7` or `1 2 5 8`

Any hints what is the best way to do that? I'm looking for a general hint, but in my implementation I have an ArrayList for each row.

Comment: The word 'parse' is incorrect here. You want to walk all possible paths to the tree.

Comment: That doesn't look like a tree, since some nodes have multiple parents. And the word "parse" doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you want to do, because from your examples it looks like you're just doing a normal [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Comment: It may become a tree if you show the edges. Is `8` a child of `4` or `5`? If both, then it's not a tree but a graph.

Comment: Yes it is a graph not a tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect using recursion is the simplest way.

something like

```
public static void visit(List<List<Integer>> tree, Visitor<List<Integer>> visitor) {
    visit0(tree, visitor, Collections.<Integer>emptyList());
}

private static void visit0(List<List<Integer>> tree, 
                           Visitor<List<Integer>> visitor, List<Integer> list) {
    if (tree.isEmpty()) {
       visitor.onList(list);
       return;
    }

    List<List<Integer>> tree2 = tree.subList(1, tree.size() - 1);
    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
    ints.add(0); // dummy entry.
    for(int n: tree.get(0)) {
        ints.set(ints.size()-1, n);
        visit0(tree2, visitor, ints);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an academic grade solution like the one presented in this paper:

["APAC: An exact algorithm for retrieving cycles and 
paths in all kinds of graphs"](http://www.scielo.oces.mctes.pt/pdf/tek/n12/n12a04.pdf) by Ricardo Simões

Brief description of the algorithm:

It is claimed that:

(a) The algorithm finds all simple paths.

(b) The algorithm finds all cycles.

(c) The algorithm terminates.

(d) The algorithm complexity is O (Cnpaths). "(...) complexity increases linearly with the 
number of paths (...)"

The author uses a pseudo-code notation - that is I believe one of most universal ones.

Comment: @kleopatra - thanks for your tips, I have updated it slightly.